# Using Variable in awk command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sh

I want to add a word at the end of each line in my text file which is stored in variable. whenever i execute shell script instead of concatenate content stored in variable variable itself  get concatenated. Below is the example for same:

**Input:**

```
cat output2.txt

12345 

att1=Ramesh^Mumbai

awk '{print $0"^$att1"}' output2.txt >output3.txt
```

**output:**

```
12345^att1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
12345^Ramesh^Mumbai
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v att1='Ramesh^Mumbai' -v OFS='^' '{print $0,att1}'
```

`-v` option allows to pass variable to `awk`

`OFS` is the output field separator (that will replace the `,` in the `print` statement by `^`)

Answer (score 0):

```
man awk:

-v var=val
Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of
the program begins. Such variable values are available to the
BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

you can use this;

```
#!/bin/bash
att1=Ramesh^Mumbai
awk -v att1=$att1 '{print $0"^"att1}' output.txt > output3.txt
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat output.txt
12345
abab
dafadf
adfaf

user@host:/tmp$, ./test.sh

user@host:/tmp$ cat output3.txt
12345^Ramesh^Mumbai
abab^Ramesh^Mumbai
dafadf^Ramesh^Mumbai
adfaf^Ramesh^Mumbai
```